# SQL Iterate (loop) a query based on list of row groupings, and merge results of each iteration into same table

Tags: sql, loops, append, iteration

***EDIT: I cannot remove the WHERE command because the data is too big to merge in full, hence I would like to iterate by country subset***

I am just getting started with SQL

I have written a simple Query that merges, removes duplicates, and creates a table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT z. Owner, z.Client,
C.[Sector], SUBSTRING(z.Address, 1, 2) AS 'Country',

CASE WHEN C.Sector ='Manufacturing' AND SUBSTRING(z.Address, 1, 2)=z.Client THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS Sample_indicator

INTO Summary_table
FROM Main_table z
LEFT JOIN Sector_key AS C ON z.Owner = C.ID

WHERE SUBSTRING(z.Address, 1, 2)="KR"
```

**I have this working, however, what I am trying to do is to "loop"/iterate this query for all distinct 'SUBSTRING(z.Address, 1, 2)'.**

Here I show KR, but I would like it to loop through a hundred or so countries.

**Finally, as a key part, I also would need the resulting table created "Summary_table" to include the results of each subsequent loop. Meaning that the table will grow storing results from each country.**

I have tried for many hours, any advice or help would be a heaven-sent. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seek for a loop, Just Try Selecting all DISTINCT countries into a Temp Table and Loop all of them with your code inside in it.

```
DECLARE @Countries TABLE
(
    [Country] VARCHAR(5)
)
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(5) -- For looping

INSERT INTO @Countries ([Country])
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Address, 1, 2)
FROM Main_table

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @Countries > 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Country = [Country]
    FROM @Countries

    /* Your code goes here ******************************/
    
    DELETE FROM @Countries
    WHERE  [Country] = @Country
END
```

Comment: One question please, there WHERE statement at the bottom should replace the one in my code? Thank you

Comment: Use your code exactly as it is, but replace this with

WHERE SUBSTRING(z.Address, 1, 2)="KR"    ==>>

WHERE SUBSTRING(z.Address, 1, 2)= @Country