# Merge/looping through an sql query with another query?

Tags: sql

I don't think my post title is correct/the best but I don't really know how to concisely explain it.

I have one SQL query

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.firstname                AS "First Name",
       c.lastname                 AS "Last Name",
       c.telephone                AS "Telephone",
       c.email                    AS "Email",
       a.name                     AS "Company Name",
       i.available_integration_id AS 'Stripe'
FROM   users u
       INNER JOIN contacts c
       ON     c.id = u.contact_id
       INNER JOIN accounts a
       ON     u.account_id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN integrations i
       ON     a.id = i.account_id
WHERE  a.id IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT a1.id
                FROM             accounts a1
                                 INNER JOIN orders o1
                                 ON               a1.id = o1.account_id
                WHERE            o1.created_at         >= '2020-10-01 00:00:00'
                )
```

This returns 600+ results

I then need to run

```
SELECT count(id), sum(amount)
FROM   transactions t
WHERE  t.order_id IN
       (SELECT o.id
       FROM    orders o
       WHERE   o.account_id = 'c59bde2a-3ff8-61ea-e449-42699342a444'
       AND     o.status     = 'completed'
       )
AND t.status = 'completed'
```

against every ID returned from the first query.

Is it possible to merge these two queries together to return one table that looks like this

```
ID, First Name, Last Name, Telephone, Email, Company Name, Stripe, Total Orders, Total Amount
```

or do I have to run the second query 600+ times and manually copy/paste the data over?

Comment: i cant comment but possible duplicate of [SQL Iterate (loop) a query based on list of row groupings, and merge results of each iteration into same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079413/sql-iterate-loop-a-query-based-on-list-of-row-groupings-and-merge-results-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not missing something, this is what you need:

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.firstname                AS "First Name",
       c.lastname                 AS "Last Name",
       c.telephone                AS "Telephone",
       c.email                    AS "Email",
       a.name                     AS "Company Name",
       i.available_integration_id AS "Stripe",
       totals.cnt_orders          AS "Total Orders",
       totals.sum_amount          AS "Total Amount"
  FROM users u
       INNER JOIN contacts c
       ON     c.id = u.contact_id
       INNER JOIN accounts a
       ON     u.account_id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN integrations i
       ON     a.id = i.account_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id, COUNT(t.id) AS cnt_orders, SUM(t.amount) AS sum_amount
                     FROM accounts a
                          INNER JOIN orders o
                          ON  o.account_id = a.id
                          INNER JOIN transactions t
                          ON  o.id  = t.order_id
                    WHERE o.status     = 'completed'
                      AND o.created_at >= '2020-10-01 00:00:00'
                    GROUP BY a.id) totals
       ON     a.id = totals.id;
```

Comment: When I try and run it I'm getting `Unknown column 'a.account_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: Adjusted, I took the foreign key name from orders instead of the primary key column that I actually select.

Comment: Now I'm getting `Unknown column 'totals.account_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Ye, it's the same thing, just corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, when I run my original query I get 644 results, when I run your query it returns 552.

Comment: From the first query you're not filtering the status, this will actually give you all the accounts with sales, if this is what you need we keep it inner joined, if not, a different join will be needed, but I'm not sure of your use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243523/discussion-between-gnqz-and-alex).